# Where should test executables be installed?

Tags: linux, packaging, cmake

I am packaging a component that will also have test executables packaged with it (ideally in a separate package from the runtime package). Ideally, I don't want to package them in /usr/bin since the name of the test executables may conflict with other components tests (e.g. `test_main`, etc). I also would like to package a CTestfile.cmake file so users can run all tests with `ctest`.

I was thinking about putting the tests under share/test//bin with the CTestfile.cmake under share/test/ so users can run `ctest /usr/share/test/<component>` to run all the tests for the component.

Is this a good location for this? Or is there another common practice used for packaging tests for linux distros?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know whether there’s a common practice shared across distribution families, but in Debian and its derivatives, `/usr/libexec/installed-tests` is used by a number of packages (see for example [`libgcab-tests`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libgcab-tests/filelist)). Each package uses a sub-directory there.

Since your `CTestfile.cmake` is presumably specific to your project, it should be installed in your project’s sub-directory rather than a potentially shared higher level directory (`/usr/share/test` or `/usr/libexec/installed-tests`).